# Unranked users have a blue minus sign by their name on their profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, reputation-leagues

I just saw that there is a blue minus sign beside my username on my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13634030/vulpini99?tab=profile).

Here's an image to show you what I mean:

> [image: vulpini99 –]

What does that mean? Is this a bug, maybe?

Comment: You've been marked for extermination. Sorry

Comment: It’s not a minus sign. This is where your reputation rank normally goes, but you are `<!-- unranked -->`, as the HTML comment inside explains.

Comment: Cross-site post on MSE: [There is an UI issue for the ranking div when a user crossed 200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332691/289905).

Comment: Yes, it is a bug. As was noted, it has also been reported on the global Meta. We will have to wait for a staff member to answer and/or fix this. Thanks for reporting it. The first comment from DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter is merely a joke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed. A thorough explanation (and haiku) is [posted on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367215/51).

Comment: And now I'm curious to read the commit comment log... does every commit have to be a haiku?